# Problem Understanding how to use Li-Ion battery charger IC

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics, charger, gsm

[image]
I want to drive a Load that consumes 2A current during data transmission for a concise amount of time, and it can tolerate a maximum of 4.4 volts ([SIM800 Series GSM](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/938871/SIMCom/SIM800C/1)). It works fine with a DC adapter and buck converter. Now I want to add battery backup. A single Li-Ion cell.

I want to use TP4056 for charging the battery. Now I have confusion about where to connect the load? If I connect the load across the battery I'll get 4.2 volts maximum and hence I can get rid of the Buck converter. The thing that confuses me is how the IC will respond in that case? And will the battery be charged properly? The Load will draw 2 amp at 5 or 10 min intervals and capacitors will aid to supply that impulse current. Then the load will be consuming a few mA (Indiaor LED, MCU in sleep mode, and SIM800 in sleep).

I've found some modules of TP4056 [like the one in this link](https://store.roboticsbd.com/battery-charger/1334-tp4056-li-ion-battery-charger-with-protection-robotics-bangladesh.html), which most probably use connection [like this EasyEDA Schematic](https://easyeda.com/Little_Arc/TP4056). According to the schematic, the module's output is connected to pin 5 of TP4056. So, what should I do, always use TP4056 for 4.2 volts or will use a MOSFET and a buck converter to switch sources?

Comment: The MOSFET will disconnect the battery. But the power will be coming through the TP4056 module. I assume the output voltage will be 4.2 volts. Isn't?

Comment: Somewhat decent information about the workings of such TP4056 modules: https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html